# How to get guild info using discord oauth?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, discord

How can i get a particular `guild info`?  It's working if i remove guilds.id, but then it only return list of all guilds i am in.
what is the correct method to get and update guild information using discord api?

This is how i'm getting my access_token:

```
const key   =  req.query.code,
options     =  {
                  href:`https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token`,  
                  code : `code=${key}`,
                  grant_type : grant_type=authorization_code`,
                  redirect_uri :`redirect_uri=${redirect}` 
                 };

    request({
        uri: `${options.href}?${options.grant_type}&${options.code}&${options.redirect_uri}`,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Basic ${creds}`,
        }
    }, (err,response, body) => {
       if(err) return console.log(err);
       console.log(body) // console log access_token
    })
```

Using access_token to make request

```
//My get request options 
    const options =  { 
            url: `https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/${guilds.id}`,
            method: 'GET',
            json: true,
            headers: {
            authorization: `${token_type} ${access_token}`}
        }

//Both of these options arent working
//token_type = bot
//token_type = Bearer
```

Gives me `401: Unauthorized`.

My access_token scope is:

```
`identify email guilds guilds.join gdm.join rpc connections`
```

Comment: I think it's just `/api/guilds/${guilds.id}`

Comment: it's showing `401: Unauthorized`. @Sasha

Comment: is your `token_type` bot or bearer

Comment: it,s bearer @Sasha

Comment: Try use your bot token to get the above url, with `bot` as the token type

Comment: it's working now, thanks @Sasha

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to get all information. You can only get one field by each `GET` request.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).